# Scientific notation question involving multiplication of factors with different power

Tags: notation

(5.32 x10(8)) * (3.54 x 10(3))
I do this by converting 3.54 to a power of 8 so:

(5.32 x10(8)) * (.0000354 x10(8)) which, when I do the math, equals .0000188328 or 1.88328 x10(-4)

HOWEVER

The answer apparently is 1.88328 x10(12)

Where / what have I messed up?

Answer (score 1):

You should have added the exponents as well:

$$
(a \times 10^8) \, (b \times 10^8) = 
(ab)\times 10^{8+8} = (ab)\times 10^{16}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Making the powers of 10 agree is a detour. You need that for *addition*, but not for multiplication. In multiplication you simply add the exponents:

$$ \begin{align}
   (5.32\times 10^8) \times (3.54 \times 10^3)
 =& (5.32 \times 3.54) \times (10^8 \times 10^3)
\\=& 18.8328 \times 10^{8+3}
\\=& (1.88328 \times 10^1) \times 10^{11}
\\=& 1.88328 \times 10^{12} \end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, it would have been more useful to push as much "just behind the comma zeroes" into the exponents, like normalized floats do, or just one digit before the comma, like in your example.